# jQuery code for automatically turn off the toggle switch

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want to add a jQuery code like when User Release the left mouse button,
the toggle switch will turn off automatically.

I can't find the similar code after I searched for it.

And here is my prototype code:

```
renderWindow.getInteractor().onLeftButtonRelease((callData) => {
    $(.switch).turnOff();
});
```

How do I fix this code?

Thank you!

Comment: Share an example code that may be fix

Answer (score 0):

Try to add quotes around selector like this `$("switch").turnOff()`

Comment: Thanks! It was a good trial. I fixed it by "attr" way.